# How to set a value for Bluetooth media volume

Tags: android, bluetooth

I`m trying to make an android app that can control Bluetooth volume. 
till now i managed to change Bluetooth volume value for calls. using this piece of code :

```
 audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int streamMaxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(6);
    int lVol = ((volumeValue / 100) * streamMaxVolume);
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(6, lVol, 0);
```

now the problem that I have is I cannot find the `int` value for streamType which is allocated for Bluetooth Media volume.

Answer (score 1):

well I found the answer.
looks like after a bluetooth device connect to the phone. in order to change the bluetooth media volume the app should wait for some amount of time. I`ve set my method to run its codes after 10sec. here it is :

```
public void strat(BtDevice btDevice){

   new Timer().schedule(
           new TimerTask() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) myContex.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                   int volumeValue = btDevice.getMusicVolume();
                   int streamMaxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(3);
                   int lVol = ((volumeValue / 100) * streamMaxVolume);
                   audioManager.setStreamVolume(3, lVol, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
               }
           },
           10000
   );
```